# Batch File in a line of a specific text file

Tags: batch-file, dos

How could I delete a part of each line in a text?

Example:

```
</td><td valign="top" style="font-weight:bold;">1100052719
</td><td valign="top" style="font-weight:bold;">1100053714
</td><td valign="top" style="font-weight:bold;">1100053777
```

I want to make it to this:

```
1100052719,1100053714,1100053777
```

I have a file named POs.txt where all those data can be seen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By way of explanation...

```
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
```

Allows us to enclose variable names in ! to indicate that we want to expand the variable at Run Time rather than at Load Time.

```
    set OutputString=
```

Defines the variable OutputString with initial empty value.

```
    for /f "tokens=3 delims=>" %%A in (Pos.txt) do set OutputString=!OutputString!%%A,
```

The text we want to keep is the 3rd token when using a delimiter of >
For each iteration (line of text in Pos.txt) we append the 3rd field (token) to OutputString along with a comma

```
    set OutputString=%OutputString:~0,-1%
```

Strips off the trailing comma by starting at the first character and saving all but the last character of OutputString

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set OutputString=
for /f "tokens=3 delims=>" %%A in (Pos.txt) do set OutputString=!OutputString!%%A,
set OutputString=%OutputString:~0,-1%
echo.%OutputString%
endlocal
pause
```

Comment: If you don't mind.. Can you also please explain to me the whole script?

Answer (score 0):

Code 1:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set OutputString=
for /f "delims=" %%a in (Pos.txt) do (
    set line=%%a
    set OutputString=!OutputString!!line:*">=!,
)
set OutputString=%OutputString:~0,-1%
echo,%OutputString%
pause
```

Code 2:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set OutputString=
for /f "delims=" %%a in (Pos.txt) do (
    set line=%%a
    set OutputString=!OutputString!!line:~-10!,
)
set OutputString=%OutputString:~0,-1%
echo,%OutputString%
pause
```